# Line thickness in VegaLite for mark: rule

Tags: vega-lite

I have [this](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-FiSLI6UY+iSIBZtqEwrbwg7dvC9i5F8gAJnG0bwsEQiHaX1n1ag4+o+NQnxYRP+pLL3cg-DgOj96Gdc5MihUahta4gCeIugMBbdFhYdgcIOcyFcZqvR9NGfFMoCNOhkGgN8zA-KwfnbA0AVLaskivSAKirB9gO0UCTVrRtq3fY1a0kQNaBJUdsWQI0AFV4BBNsFjCHV8MovBKmqDRKyweAfCUZJVGgBgAGFYFsAQWB1Uw32mQZhlGLA8mQw80Oky8H3XEDXzYkx3U-ewBB-Fwow0yAOJqZ1WBBXwAA1yDWIolJ0qhoFaPx5B0WBpD9KJxjAO48gSZSunLSY4CUVt1KwrQXyWIgIKg5yYONeC-QowCoF8VB+FAl0sNkl4JKWAcNiHPYRwy44ZnBNFbnuSrgVBPxeKTHT50XZdp1XDSoHoEgAAU2B0M9hnIaJigy4KyimsBgtC+QHSdXqfG9KAT1gEaLwoNSKHwVp0wxEt3HEVC8BILIcjGxzzXpAkuu6szbAjShJ0s5Ld0jAC8B4Ybzy42B1CwPZkl8RAvmie5erurAp2uqBenDCNJHIIoSnNFjQniizsDqPC9SwSJow84MWBnOIAE41jiKcqZHMD4saKCrAAGT9IgwjYHwwCe5AlAKMBDGSQwsCKHZQqAljjTJynqapuI33AxmWFZr0Oa5nm+YFt9hbAAA2KdxYoSXSbyCmqZp6mFYZyDlbZtWlG51RNcFqAdf1w3ifwqxpfNqmdithLbdVzmHY1-mXcgHWpziD28Kl02ZYtumpGtpmoBCXnTDAPg4FcWgs4jnXol1gpolj43vYT324nl5JFZtqwM6ULOc9gPOC+18hdZ2AoAA5y5Jyuzdly269Tlgm5bohc6tDuhZRlU0aJuOTeHi3-bHwPG7YTPs+ntvZ61+esDiU2CnJgevagH2R91gOle33fW-bo-XaugoY+7T347X2n74bqAewdDZ2UJ6VAe8Z751fpHMaTll4V2vlXEetd6Zb0AXkYB9AkznggQfKBhcu79y-ivIeidzb-zTpAIBIDsHDFwS-AhWBdZLyBN-VeZC4gb1QQ-dBmDQE4OfofRhYBogG2IQgyAN8LZKgoSwahWCwH0KEZ3LAojL4-w4UUWRVh5H8LoYI-BKiRFiPgYPRBv84h303jwqhGCaGKIMXPN+qiDZ1ASBSEAQggA) plot and I am trying to make the dashed line really thin compared to the others, but can't quite figure it out. I've tried size on the actual mark-rule encoding part, as well as strokeWidth in the config (which at least the vega example [here](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/rule/) suggests is what i want) but no joy. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that non-integer stroke widths are rounded up in rule marks; however this is not the case for line marks. If you replace your `rule` layer with this, it seems to do what you wish:

```
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"date": "2019-12-10", "metric": 100},
          {"date": "2019-12-16", "metric": 100}
        ]
      },
      "mark": {"type": "line", "strokeWidth": 0.5, "color": "black"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal", "timeUnit": "monthdate"},
        "y": {"field": "metric", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
```

Here is the result ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDGD2B2AzAlgc0gLjKCFIDdkBTAd020gGcAXAJ1gGsjzI6BDeSgBzdqPmqQAvgBpwuSGwAeySuRy48qWsgAm5RGwA2lImMV4tbAEZEtAQXiotzLAAZ9ByEdNaAYgkFZIAWwCuurAAtJQclEEAzHZ2kI6KziZmHgIAysgAXrZgAIwArHESLkmeAOpEaAAWXlDwsLQ+2rHi8dTI1DbJ1b4BRMGhnJHRTQZQre1EnWmZ5HkFeGMdpeWoVSy19Y3NYELiouKQACSU0BVEDSxV1FyUGAD0t-hEqGwAdKhtFX7GL8iwt8enBoPJ5sIJaNpEB4AFheACtKAhhlBVGxqGx5JB4GwfFlICi0cJHAkAJ5EWjkADaWwU8QatAY8i2LWJXFx4PgzDmEmQAjJXFgRmouJ8CFg1AQnKZEn5POqwEgKC0NnUWDofj0UBo9CYLBIFQhsU1GSy2WiOxGexGrDaNkZI3mRCkXSRVo4JzqLB8alUtq5eEQnk9PT6YUGMT9UADqWN5AATA4pXhYIhELpqgn7ZGlpUuusGlpIFLLU5+HBVDz0FgaU5xQLWlxKYncPKUGYVVAAKSG1gs3EARz8HDGqOQj0JTYgLeIWnbviIdGQ0G71F7a1gXqxBfN9oAuhHIFI7ZnI9PZ-jJcfRqvvEKfPzaI0I-NkDiAKrwNqezwVc8u+2SGQ5Cra1xnIeA-CVERRkXBgAGFYD8AQWBRYluyKCwrFtextwtfdUKrCcTzbFguyfK9WRYAchzaEcxzIgDZAxBYiAADXIIJcjsYtMyoaBtCyeVVHXNgeUpBwck4nccIMbinDgLQPQIy8FVPT15xUJd6JXCjvFqDdH0I5wnn4dtqx49DOiDQIQlDKJw0IwxEncTwphNfIHOg0CsHAyCPMgZNU3nOMM0vKB6BIAAFNhVHLKxyAAdheXJCOkxRUu2LZZLM5FUXRJT-3wbR1SAsAqUvQTUVxeNsgATiCbJY3q8MoBxBclywU0uLIiqhRYaq6oa+qADZu1ajSZjNJsdyLLlfF4BlgO0tkeU5TU6EYIgSjUagKnIOwkqgmABUUqBjCMaAGVkvBS1gWLK2wJsDwxVsZ2Qyrl2vUYznvR9oLfD8uhFAQf3eq6JHwigXtnMbFw+nSoCogQaNaMd0uk7c932Ehtt2rB4s4olThzYKQskPxxUoGNFs+zEJXHPAeBiismNgBssCiQ6bEQap8cOlQVmqWMCdOsVxR8chclyYs8VytMSurGWCSwMqDB6qq7Fq+rGtNUb1Nh7wABkVoqNgILAcnkC0F4wFIzsJYiMG1b6jWBu17JdbalgjY5E2zYtq2be7LssCG2NHcV9XNcGhqPfGw3jdNrRzdaAPbcgYOwFD8Pf28fqtfqiJY-1qBvaIX2k-96204z2Nsmz97c5d-OdcOmH2qgAAREStGJMA+DgR5aF76uEqGl54vr3rG6jt2i-byAu8t3v+9gQfh6D8ghoiF4AA5J8j12tbnlhF57vuiAHsl18OjPchhKWuSd6fD+yQvW71+fT+Xi-V6vwOb4mtkF4NV97OxnsNY+3gv7n0vkPf+ds8a5BeHXR+EcwEv2anOT23goiqD7gKdkqAYG-zgSPPGXUpRPygHnaO7t37YKgLg-BSoKzELXvA9Om896oJztQpu0dYyQMYXYPB9AWFWDYX-MhmcH6ULQc-Zub8WofxYEwsRhDJGkI3njMOPCG58PAdkKEQjIBqIIawle7DpHxV0XI3hkAaHa1yCYsx4iiGWKkdosANjQEKOjiNehcdhGiPMRIjxWiAE6OktNCAOwhBAA)):
[image]